# Retrieving Validation Attributes in MVC HtmlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, html-helper

I am developing a `MVC 4` `HtmlHelper` (Razor) to monitor the length of a string as it is entered into a `TextBox`/`TextArea` control.  Here is the start of the helper.

```
public static MvcHtmlString CharacterCounterFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var validationAttributes =
        helper.GetValidationAttributesFromExpression(expression);

    StringLengthAttribute stringLengthAttribute =
        validationAttributes.OfType<StringLengthAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();

    if (stringLengthAttribute == null)
    {
        var propertyName = helper.GetPropertyNameFromExpression(expression);
        throw new Exception(
            string.Format(MvcResources.MissingStringLengthValidationAttribute,
                propertyName));
    }

    StringLengthAttribute stringLengthAttribute =
        validationAttributes.OfType<StringLengthAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();

    /*
    ** More code...
    */
}
```

The key piece of code here is the first method statement where I use the following HtmlHelper extension method `GetValidationAttributesFromExpression()` method to retrieve all of the property's `ValidationAttributes`.

```
public static IEnumerable<ValidationAttribute>
    GetValidationAttributesFromExpression<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var propertyName = htmlHelper.GetPropertyNameFromExpression(expression);
    Type type = typeof (TModel);
    var prop = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    return prop.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ValidationAttribute>();
}
```

This works well if I define my DataAnnotations directly in the model being edited, for example:

```
public class MyModel {

    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name must not exceed {0} characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // More properties...
}
```

If I change this model to use the `MetadataType` attribute and use a class interface to define the `Data Annotations` as follows, the call to `GetValidationAttributesFromExpression()` always returns null.

```
public interface IMyModel {

    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name must not exceed {0} characters")]
    string Name { get; set; }

    // More properties...
}

[MetadataType(typeof(IMyModel))]
public class MyModel : IMyModel {

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // More properties...
}
```

I had expected that both methods of defining the `DataAnnotationAttribute` would have resulted with the same expression model, but it appears this is not the case.

Can anyone tell me how I might access the `ValidationProperties` when defined using the 'MetaDataType' attribute?